# How to access flutter Shared preferences on the android end (using java)

Tags: android, flutter, sharedpreferences, flutter-dependencies

I have the following function in dart to set a particular boolean preference value.

```
_switchPersistentNotifications() {
  setState(() {
    isPersistentNotificationEnabled = !isPersistentNotificationEnabled;
  });
  widget.preferences.setBool(
      "isPersistentNotificationEnabled", isPersistentNotificationEnabled);
}
```

This function sets the value of `isPersistentNotificationEnabled` preference.

Now on the native android end, I am supposed to use this shared preference value. Here's what I have done so far.

```
SharedPreferences preferences =
                    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
                // check if the state change notification is to be shown
                if (preferences.getBoolean("flutter.isStateChangeNotificationEnabled", false)) {
                    showConnectionStateChangeNotification();
                }
```

And the if condition never gets evaluated to true. I also tried printing all the existing preference values using the code below.

```
Map<String, ?> allEntries = preferences.getAll();
            for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : allEntries.entrySet()) {
                Log.d("map values", entry.getKey() + ": " + entry.getValue().toString());
            }
```

And it only presents the values that the Android has created (using java).

Any help in accessing the preference values is greatly appreciated.
Thank You.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Sorry this answer is coming late, just got the answer from flutter github page.

What you can do to accomplish this is:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("FlutterSharedPreferences", MODE_PRIVATE);
```

then if you want to read e.g. "myValue" key, you have to add "flutter." prefix:

```
String value = prefs.getString("flutter."+key, null);
```

Comment: Great guy, great answer

Comment: Can you please link the Flutter github page instead?

Comment: Here https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/65759