# Read shared preferences in Flutter app that were previously stored in a native app

Tags: flutter, migration, sharedpreferences, flutter-platform-channel

I have the following problem: right now there is an app in the PlayStore that is written in native code (both iOS and Android) which I'm planning on migrating to flutter. My aim is that the users don't notice there were changes under the hood but can continue using the app like before. For that I need to migrate the shared preferences as well. This is, however, quite difficult. In the native Android application I stored the relevant shared preference like this:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences(
    "storage",
    Context.MODE_PRIVATE
);

sharedPrefs.putString('guuid', 'guuid_value');
editor.apply();
```

which results in a file being created at this path:

```
/data/data/patavinus.patavinus/shared_prefs/storage.xml
```

with this content:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<map>
    <int name="guuid" value="guuid_value" />
</map>
```

If I use shared_prefences in Flutter to obtain this value by doing this:

```
final sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
sharedPreferences.getString('guuid');
```

it returns null because it looks for

`/data/data/patavinus.patavinus/shared_prefs/FlutterSharedPreferences.xml` which is the file that is written to when using shared_preferences in Flutter to store shared preferences. Because the shared prefs were written in native app context, the file is obviously not there.

Is there any way to tell Flutter to look for `/data/data/patavinus.patavinus/shared_prefs/storage.xml` without having to use platform channel?

I know how this works the other way around like it's mentioned here: [How to access flutter Shared preferences on the android end (using java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55225207/how-to-access-flutter-shared-preferences-on-the-android-end-using-java). This way is easy because in Android you can choose to prepend Flutter's prefix. However, in Flutter you can't.

I am also aware of this plugin: https://pub.dev/packages/native_shared_preferences however, I can't believe that a third party plugin is the recommended way. Also, I have spread the relevant shared preferences across multiple resource files. In this plugin, you can only set one (by specifying the string resource `flutter_shared_pref_name`).

Comment: You can use `MethodChannel`s. See [this article](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels).

Comment: He says he doens't want to use a `PlatformChannel`

Comment: Flutter uses it's own name of the sharedprefs https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/shared_preferences/shared_preferences/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/sharedpreferences/MethodCallHandlerImpl.java check here. If your using same name that stored in Android preference then I belice flutter shared_prefs can read. not tested though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since there was no satisfying answer to my question that works for both of the major operating systems and taking into account the distribution over multiple resource files, I have written a platform channel solution myself.

On **Android** (Kotlin) I let the caller provide a "file" argument because it's possible to have the data spread over multiple resource files (like I described in my question).

```
package my.test

import android.content.*
import androidx.annotation.NonNull
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel

class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
    private val CHANNEL = "testChannel"

    override fun configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)
        MethodChannel(flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger, CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler {
            call, result ->
            when (call.method) {
                "getStringValue" -> {
                    val key: String? = call.argument<String>("key");
                    val file: String? = call.argument<String>("file");

                    when {
                        key == null -> {
                            result.error("KEY_MISSING", "Argument 'key' is not provided.", null)
                        }
                        file == null -> {
                            result.error("FILE_MISSING", "Argument 'file' is not provided.", null)
                        }
                        else -> {
                            val value: String? = getStringValue(file, key)
                            result.success(value)
                        }
                    }
                }
                else -> {
                    result.notImplemented()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun getStringValue(file: String, key: String): String? {
        return context.getSharedPreferences(
                file,
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE
        ).getString(key, null);
    }
}
```

On **iOS** (Swift) this is not necessary as I'm working with `UserDefaults`

```
@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    let controller : FlutterViewController = window?.rootViewController as! FlutterViewController
    let platformChannel = FlutterMethodChannel(
      name: "testChannel",
      binaryMessenger: controller.binaryMessenger
    )

    platformChannel.setMethodCallHandler({
      [weak self] (call: FlutterMethodCall, result: FlutterResult) -> Void in
      guard call.method == "getStringValue" else {
        result(FlutterMethodNotImplemented)
        return
      }

      if let args: Dictionary<String, Any> = call.arguments as? Dictionary<String, Any>,
        let number: String = args["key"] as? String, {
        self?.getStringValue(key: key, result: result)
        return
      } else {
        result(
          FlutterError.init(
            code: "KEY_MISSING",
            message: "Argument 'key' is not provided.", 
            details: nil
          )
        )
      }
    })

    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
}
    
private func getStringValue(key: String, result: FlutterResult) -> String? {
  let fetchedValue: String? = UserDefaults.object(forKey: key) as? String
  result(fetchedValue)
}
```

I'd wish for the `SharedPreferences` package to add the possibility of omitting the flutter prefix, enabling the developer to migrate content seamlessly from native apps.

I also wrote a blog post that explains the problem and the solution in a little bit more details: https://www.flutterclutter.dev/flutter/tutorials/read-shared-preferences-from-native-apps/2021/9753/

Comment: This is indeed annoying and I cannot believe you and I are the only two people on earth migrating from native Android to Flutter and want to keep preferences? This is a major flaw on the developers especially considering how widely SharedPreferences is used. Thanks for asking this Q and providing your answer.

Answer (score 6):

As suggested [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/35862#issuecomment-624432969) you can get the native file's content and copy it to a new file. You can copy the content to flutter's storage file when the user upgrades to your flutter app for the first time.

Comment: This is indeed a nice suggestion for the Android platform. The major drawback ist however that it does not work for iOS this way :(.

Comment: On iOS it seems they only prefix the keys with `flutter.`. So creating a platform channel would be easier than you think, you can create a similar function to [this](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/2fb8bf023a43ef93b2f372f277fa16399d79b744/packages/shared_preferences/shared_preferences/ios/Classes/FLTSharedPreferencesPlugin.m#L69) without the flutter prefix.

Answer (score 4):

Best option is to store shared preferences in native part in same file as SharedPreferences plugin does it. So it means to do like that:

1. In Java code replace your SharedPreferences code, with same key, as it is in plugin: `SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences("FlutterSharedPreferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);`
2. In native part save all preferences with prefix "flutter.". So in native part you will get needed preferences like this: `String test = sharedPref.getString("flutter.test", "");`

Comment: This is not an option as I don't have access to the native apps and can not migrate the keys. I only have the existing native apps and the desire to migrate to Flutter.

Comment: @Schnodderbalken You can migrate to flutter only by creating apps on flutter. And if you are making apps on flutter, you can still write native code.

Comment: You suggest "store shared preferences in native part in same file as SharedPreferences plugin does it". But the preferences are ALREADY stored. There are native apps out there that have NOT stored it with flutter prefix. So how do I access them? That's what my question is about.

Comment: @Schnodderbalken You can read them using specific preferences key and store them in new file, which one is using same key as flutter is using.

Answer (score 0):

> I am also aware of this plugin: https://pub.dev/packages/native_shared_preferences however, I can't believe that a third party plugin is the recommended way.

I think the third party plugin is just fine. The best thing about flutter is its amazing community that keeps contributing thoroughly to the ecosystem. That said, I would not recommend keeping using the non-official library. So you could test migrating your shared preferences behind the scenes.

- In your `initState` query for flutter shared preferences.
- If they exist, skip.
- If they don't exist, query for native shared preferences, copy if exist

And done. This will help with the migration IMHO.

Comment: to be honest this is not the ideal way of doing things. I am interested in making a plugin for this.

Answer (score 0):

My choice is to treat it just as a file.
In flutter read the android shared preference file

```
/data/data/patavinus.patavinus/shared_prefs/storage.xml
```

take the values in the way you handle other xml file.

If you want to make some changes, don't use sharedPrefs.put, Instead write into the file **(/data/data/patavinus.patavinus/shared_prefs/storage.xml
)**  using file's write method in flutter

Comment: @Schnodderbalken I don't know about iOS since I've not worked on it?

Comment: I understand. But that's what my question is about. I am seeking for a solution that works for both OS.

Comment: If you know how to read write in a file in android & iOS that's enough.
put a if condition to check if the app runs on android, and write it in a file using native method(java) & method channel , in else block do it iOS native way & method channel

Answer (score 0):

May be it is too late, but for future searchings it could be helpful.
Here is my approach to get necessary token and one int value from native apps.

First you need [path_provider](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider) to find necessary files, [plist_parser](https://pub.dev/packages/plist_parser) for iOs because iOs stores User Defaults as .plist file, and [xml](https://pub.dev/packages/xml) to read .xml file with Shared Preferences in Android.

How to find iOs native values:

```
if (Platform.isIOS) {
  // Find the dir of the app.
  final appDocumentsDir = await getLibraryDirectory();
    // Create a list of contents in this dir, which includes files and dirs. 
    List contents = appDocumentsDir.listSync();
    // Find in the list the dir with user preferences
    Directory? prefsDir = contents.firstWhereOrNull((element) => element is Directory && element.path.contains('Preferences'));
    if (prefsDir != null) {
      // Get contents of the dir named 'Preferences'
      List subContents = prefsDir.listSync();
      // Find .plist file with package name of your app.
      File? prefsFile = subContents.firstWhereOrNull((element) => element is File && element.path.contains('com.your_app.plist'));
      if (prefsFile != null) {
        // Parse the file 
        final plist = PlistParser().parseBinaryFileSync(prefsFile.path);
        // With loop find necessary items
        for (final item in plist.entries) {
          if (item.key == 'access_token') {
            print('${item.value as String}');
            // your code to handle the value 
          }
          if (item.key == 'city_id') {
            print('${item.value as int}');
            // your code to handle the value 
          }
          // Here is an example to get stored data of Swift struct 
          if (item.key == 'selectedCity') {
            // Create decoder
            const asciiDecoder = AsciiDecoder();
            // Get ASCII value, which stored like [56, 104, 92 ...]
            final asciiValues = item.value;
            // Convert it to string.
            // It returns json string
            final cityJson = asciiDecoder.convert(asciiValues);
            // Convert json to the class with its factory.
            // You may use https://app.quicktype.io to convert JSON
            // to Flutter class and create necessary factories
            final city = City.fromRawJson(cityJson);
            // your code to handle the object of this class
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

How to get values from shared preferences in Android.

```
import 'package:xml/xml.dart' as xml;
// Name it somehow you like for example 'xml' as far as it conflicts with dart.io
// You will need dart.io for Platform

if (Platform.isAndroid) {
  // Find the dir of you app by package name
  final appDocumentsDir = Directory('/data/data/com.your_app');
  // Create a list of contents in this dir, which includes files and dirs. 
  List contents = appDocumentsDir.listSync();
  // Find in the list the dir with shared preferences
  Directory? prefsDir = contents.firstWhereOrNull((element) => element is Directory && element.path.contains('shared_prefs'));
  if (prefsDir != null) {
    // Get contents of the dir named shared_prefs
    List subContents = prefsDir.listSync();
    // Find .xml file with shared preferences.
    // Check the name of this file in native code, or
    // find it in Device Explorer of Android Studio.
    File? prefsFile = subContents.firstWhereOrNull((element) => element is File && element.path.contains('your_name.xml'));
    if (prefsFile != null) {
        // Create XML document
        final document = xml.XmlDocument.parse(prefsFile.readAsStringSync());
        // Loop from root to children
        for (final items in document.children) {
          // Loop for each child
          for (final item in items.childElements) {
            // Read item as Sting
            final itemString = item.outerXml;
            // Check for your name in prefs
            if (itemString.contains('access_token')) {
              // If prefs store it as String it will look like
              // '<string name="access_token">the token value</string>'
              // Get the value in this key
              final value = item.innerXml;
              // your code to handle the value
            }
            // For int or float you need to do something different.
            // Because prefs store it like '<int name="city_id" value="3" />'
            if (itemString.contains('city_id')) {
              // 'item.attributes' will return a list like 
              // [name="city_id", value="3"]
              // and you need to get second value and parse it to int
              final cityId = int.parse(item.attributes[1].value);
              // You code to handle the value 'cityId'
            }
          }
        }
      } 
    } 
  } 
}
```

.firstWhereOrNull is a function from very useful lib of [getX](https://pub.dev/packages/get).
Or you may use extension below.

```
extension IterableX<T> on Iterable<T> {
  T? firstWhereOrNull(bool Function(T) test) {
  T? firstItem;
  for (var item in this) {
    if (test(item)) {
      firstItem = item;
      break;
    }
  }
  return firstItem;
  }
}
```