# How to access android Shared preferences(using java) on the flutter end (using dart)?

Tags: android, flutter, sharedpreferences, flutter-dependencies, flutter-sharedpreference

I have tried to many days but getting null value on flutter side.

I have shared the code. Please let me know is there anything wrong?

I also refer the link [How to access flutter Shared preferences on the android end (using java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55225207/how-to-access-flutter-shared-preferences-on-the-android-end-using-java) but it it exact opposite my requirements.

MainActivity.java

```
SharedPreferences  prefs = contextApplication.getSharedPreferences("preference", MODE_PRIVATE);
//save in shared prefs
prefs.edit().putString("hashMapEventsInBg_session", hashMapString).apply();
```

main.dart

```
 SharedPreferences  sp = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  var demosession = sp.getString("hashMapEventsInBg_session");
```

Answer (score 3):

What you can do is:

#### 1. Set the name in `getSharedPreferences` to `"FlutterSharedPreferences"`.

> getSharedPreferences("FlutterSharedPreferences", MODE_PRIVATE)

#### 2. Always prefix `"flutter."` in the key of any pair.

> putString("flutter.test", "Hello")

#### Kotlin Code.

```
  val prefs: SharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("FlutterSharedPreferences", MODE_PRIVATE)
  prefs.edit().putString("flutter.test", "Hello").apply()
```

#### 3. Read the value like this in Flutter.

```
String test = (await SharedPreferences.getInstance()).getString("test"); //returns Hello.
```

Comment: Hi ,
 have updated the boolean value inside native code ,when I tried to retrive value from flutter side , I didn't get the updated value, please help

Comment: Can you share the code in a new question and send the link?

Comment: It is giving null value only. The above code is not working for me. Please help

Answer (score 2):

if you use android java

on android side

```
 Map<String, String> data = yourdata;
 SharedPreferences preferences = this.getSharedPreferences("FlutterSharedPreferences",MODE_PRIVATE);
 JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(message);
 String jsonString = jsonObject.toString();
 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
 editor.putString("flutter.msg",jsonString);
 editor.apply();
```

on flutter side

```
SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    if(preferences.containsKey('msg')){
       final message  =  preferences.getString('msg');
        Map data = json.decode(message);
         
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Package for using shared preference in flutter : https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences

To understand more about using shared preference in flutter  : https://medium.com/flutterdevs/using-sharedpreferences-in-flutter-251755f07127

https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/persistence/key-value